# downloading currencies data with fimport package r

Tags: r, yahoo-finance, r-package

I'm trying to download currencies historical data from yahoo finance using fimport package in R. the function i'm using is `yahooSeries`.But the problem is that for some currencies its work like:
NZD=X,JPY=X.

But for some currencies its not working, for example:
NZDAUD=X and the error is:

```
trying URL 'http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=NZDAUD=X&a=&b=&c=&d=11&e=08&f=2016&g=d&x=.csv'

cannot open URL 'http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=NZDAUD=X&a=&b=&c=&d=11&e=08&f=2016&g=d&x=.csv': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in yahooSeries(symbols = "NZDAUD=X", from = "2010-01-01") : 
trying to get slot "data" from an object of a basic class ("character") with no slots".
```

Can someone understand what the problem is?
there are currencies that can't been downloaded by Yahoo finance?
thanks.

Comment: why don't you use both possibilities and `try/catch` structure ? Can you give examples ?

Comment: what you mean both possibilities? the issue is that some currencies return errors.

Comment: I didn't get you were using a specific package. You could try using the url in with basic import function, e.g. following https://www.r-bloggers.com/getting-data-from-an-online-source/

Comment: what is the advantage if there is already a package for downloading from yahoo?

Comment: If there were no problem there would be no question. If the package is not perfect, building your own solution is a possibility

Comment: ok, now i understand you. thanks. But maybe there is another possibility that yahoo finance dont support all currencues data?